# Tkinter Listbox - Selects ALL in listbox instead of what I choose

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am running into a problem and have been searching, but haven't found anything similar that I recognize. There was one link that showed how to run a loop after a delay of 200ms, but I couldn't follow the code.

My problem is that I got some multiple listbox code, ran it, and it pulled up what I wanted BUT did not allow me to choose a single option.  The instance I chose anything in the listbox, the box was destroyed and it pulled in ALL of the values instead of just the one I chose. One I figure this out I am certain selecting multiple will work also.

Not sure how to put this into a loop, delay it, stall it, so that I can go through the list and choose an item(s).  Any code links or resources would be appreciative as well to do the reading.  Thanks.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class PDF:
    #def __init__(self):
    #    pass

    def pdfItemExtract(self) -> None:
        

        # Create tkinter Tk based Main Window
        self.master_win = Tk()                              # Primary widget win.  Tk GUI style
        self.master_win.title("Resume Extract Options")
        self.master_win.geometry('300x300')

        # Vert scroll capability on right side of window
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master_win)
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        label = Label(self.master_win,
                      text="Select the languages below :  ",
                      font=("Times New Roman", 10),
                      padx=10, pady=10)
        label.pack()                                        #Centers lbl (feature of pack)

        # Widget expands horizontally and
        # vertically by assigning both to
        # fill option
        self.list_box = Listbox(self.master_win,
                                selectmode="MULTIPLE",
                                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        self.list_box.pack(padx=10, pady=10,
                  expand=YES, fill="both")

        x = ["C", "C++", "C#", "Java", "Python",
             "R", "Go", "Ruby", "JavaScript", "Swift",
             "SQL", "Perl", "XML"]

        for each_item in range(len(x)):
            self.list_box.insert(END, x[each_item])
            self.list_box.itemconfig(each_item, bg="light blue")

        # Attach listbox to vertical scrollbar
        yscrollbar.config(command=self.list_box.yview)      #yview: allows lbox vert scrollable

        self.list_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.callback)
        self.master_win.mainloop()
        return self.selected_items

    def callback(self, eventObject):                                # Call back generates var. We call it 'event'
        print(eventObject)
        self.selected_items = self.list_box.get(0, last=END)
        self.master_win.destroy()
```

/* -------- Main Prog -------- */

```
from m_pdf import *

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pdf = PDF()
    extract_list = pdf.pdfItemExtract()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you used `self.selected_items = self.list_box.get(0, last=END)`, it will get all the items in the listbox.

You should use `self.selected_items = [self.list_box.get(x) for x in self.list_box.curselection()]` instead.

Comment: Thank you!!!  Sorry didn't answer sooner.  Texas weather.